# How to resolve an issue with tab navigation?

Tags: reactjs, carousel, react-slick

There is a slider that was created with react-slick library. Every single slide has an interactive element inside of it(a button for example). When user wants to navigate using tab, the slider works unexpectedly. Here is the link to the example. You can add a button element in each slide under img element and try to navigate using tab. You will see the problem I'm talking about. If you know how to handle it in the right way, please tell me. Here is the link
https://codesandbox.io/s/ppwkk5l6xx?file=/index.js